# How do I "Reload" Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: 11.10, software-center

using Ubuntu Software Center in 11.10 seems to be impossible to reload. For example, when I go to Software Sources and activate the Universe repo, USC does not automatically reload and so activate the Universe Repo. And I can find no "Reload" button as exists in synaptic. But on a clean install I can't install synaptic because I can't get the Universe repo activated cause I don't know how to get USC to reload.

I wish synaptic was kept in the Main repo.
[image]

Comment: You can go on terminal and issue sudo apt-get update until somebody answers your concern, It is same as reload only executed on terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure about 11.10, but I'm using 11.04 and added repositories are shown on left hand side pane and when clicked all softwares under them are listed. I prefer using synaptics as well though.

Comment: the leftside pane is gone in 11.10 USC.

Comment: So I've updated to 11.10 and found that there is "Software Sources" when I added new repository and opened USC. I found it started after reloading. I can see repository when I clock on small tick besides All Softwares.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (you can do ALT+F2 and type `gnome-terminal`) then type :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then type your password and wait until it is finished. Once it is finished you can close the terminal and reopen the Ubuntu Software Center.

There should be a way to do it without opening a terminal but I don't have 11.10 so I can't search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always run the update manager and check for updates before installing software. That might be a good practice in any case. That will update all your sources.